# Из БД MSSQL удалить все ссылки

Tags: php, sql, регулярные-выражения, sql-server

В БД tсть поле product_description, в котором содержится описание товара в текстовом формате. Но попадаются и внешние ссылки, которые надо удалить из описания.
SQL запросом в MSSQL 5 не получится этого сделать, как я понимаю..
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать это на php.

Пример поля product_description:

```
текст ..... <a href = "site.ru"> САЙТ </a> бла бла
```

Надо, чтобы получилось: `текст .....  САЙТ бла бла`

```
<?php  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db_user', 'db_password'); 
mysql_select_db('db_name'); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8'); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `product_description` where `description` like '%www.goalsite.ru%'"; 

$res = mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 

$newankor = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $row['description']);

mysql_query("UPDATE `product_description` SET `description` = $newankor where `product_id` = $row['product_id']"); 
} 

mysql_close($db); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лови . 
Удалить определенные теги с контентом. Вот код как удалить только определенные теги из строки , также удаляет содержимое тега

```
<?php

    $string = "<p>Awesome <a href='#'>lol</a></p><b> Website</b><i> by Narayan</i>. Thanks for visiting";
    $tags = array("a", "i");

    echo preg_replace('#<(' . implode( '|', $tags) . ')(?:[^>]+)?>.*?</\1>#s', '', $string);

?>
```

Выводит

```
Awesome

Website. Thanks for visiting
```

Comment: У человека строки - в базе данных.

Comment: Мне именно надо удалить <a href = "......">  </a>, а анкор надо, чтобы остался

Answer (score 0):

Вот

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_StripHTML] (@HTMLText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Start INT
    DECLARE @End INT
    DECLARE @Length INT
    SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
    SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
    SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    WHILE @Start > 0 AND @End > 0 AND @Length > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @HTMLText = STUFF(@HTMLText,@Start,@Length,'')
        SET @Start = CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText)
        SET @End = CHARINDEX('>',@HTMLText,CHARINDEX('<',@HTMLText))
        SET @Length = (@End - @Start) + 1
    END
    RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(@HTMLText))
END
GO
```

[User Defined Function to Strip HTML](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/16/sql-server-udf-user-defined-function-to-strip-html-parse-html-no-regular-expression/)

[MySQL: UDF to remove HTML Tag from the String Data](https://www.dbrnd.com/2016/03/mysql-udf-to-remove-html-tag-from-the-string-data/)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне надо удалить только конкретные теги на ссылку, а не все